# How do I iterate over a Map without using an Iterator or set?

Tags: java, collections, interface, dictionary

In Java, I am trying to iterate over a map to complete the implementation of the `putAll()` method from the `Map` interface. However, I can't use `keyset()`, `entryset()` nor `values()` to do this which means that I can't call an iterator for this purpose.

I am stumped as to how to go about it without an iterator.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, my job is to implement all of the Map methods without using these three. I am stumped as to how to implement such methods as `putAll()` without an iterator.

Comment: Why can't you use any of these methods?

Comment: Is it you teacher that's not allowing you to?

Comment: `keySet()`, `entrySet()` and `values()` are the only way to access the contents without knowing the keys in advance. Either this is a trick question (answer: you can't) or there's some other information that you haven't provided.  Also, you should add the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: @JimGarrison No this isn't a trick question. And thanks for the derisive comment about adding the homework tag.

Comment: You may have made up that the comment about the homework tag was derisive.  It was not.  That is the custom on SO.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html - there are no methods other than you mentioned in `Map` interface to iterate through it. Are you sure you are not misinterpreting your task?

Comment: @Vladimir Is there a way to message you privately?

Comment: @so1201431 derisive?  It's poor SO etiquette of *you* to post a question like this *without* the homework tag.

Comment: Maybe it means that when implementing your map you can't use *your own* keySet/entrySet/values views?

Comment: @KevinBourrillion No, we were instructed to completely leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Map` is a `SortedMap`, then you can do this:

```
SortedMap<K, V> partialMap = wholeMap;
while (!partialMap.isEmpty()) {
  K key = partialMap./* left as an exercise to the reader */;
  partialMap = partialMap.tailMap(
      key,
      false // exclusive, so does not include key
      );
}
```

You can find an explanation of `tailMap` in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap%28K,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

From HashMap code :

```
for (Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> i = m.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e = i.next();
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
```

Now maybe you should explain why you can't use an iterator like this.

Or give us the implementation code so we can see how you store KV entries maybe we could help more with that. Only by using Map interface's methods there is no other way than with the 3 methods you are restricted to use

Answer (score -2):

```
Map mp = new HashMap();
        Set s = mp.keySet();
        Iterator itr = s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object value = mp.get(itr.next());
        }
```

I have no idea why you are not able to use it. The implementation is done in the code above.

Comment: -1, violates explicit restriction in the question.  And no generics either :-(